# array doesn't show correct values

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to show the values of the array after getting it from user

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE  3
void main (void)
{
    int data[MAXSIZE];
    int n ,i ;

    for (i = 0;i < MAXSIZE ;i++ )
    {
        printf("Enter array [%d]: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&data[n]);

    }

    printf("data before sort\n");
    printf("===================\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAXSIZE ;i++ )
        printf("Value[%d]:%d\n",i+1,data[n]);





}
```

input :

Enter array [1]: 3

Enter array [2]: 2

Enter array [3]: 1

output:

data before sort

===================

Value[1]:1

Value[2]:1

Value[3]:1

I want to show data entered data but it shows the last entered value

in this case it's 1

Comment: `data[n]` -> `data[i]`

Comment: What is `n` supposed to be used for anyway? Just remove it.

Comment: Yet another rookie mistake that could have easily been avoided had **compiler warnings** been enabled: `error: variable 'n' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace instances of `n` with `i`.  Variable`i` is being used to track the count in each `for` loop and `n` is never set or initialized.